# WiFi ONLY works if Ethernet is plugged in

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi

I have a headless Raspberry PI model B, with a RealTek 802.11n dongle, running the very latest version of Raspbian.

I would like to configure both the wired and wireless connections so that I can choose to plugin to the Ethernet if need be.   However, most of the time I would like to connect via wireless.  The wireless network utilizes WPA2 Personal with a hidden SSID.

- If I boot with *both* the Ethernet and Wifi plugged in, the network
  connectivity will work over both Ethernet and WiFi.
- If I boot without the Ethernet, I can not connect to the Pi via WiFi.

  - About 15-30 seconds after plugging in the Ethernet, both Ethernet and
    WiFi network connectivity will work.
- If I unplug the Ethernet, I can no longer connect to the Pi via WiFi.

Below is my */etc/network/interfaces* file.    What changes do I need to make so I can use the Wireless connection without the wire? :-)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet static
   metric 1
   address 192.168.0.144
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.0.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
   metric 2
   address 192.168.0.244
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.0.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
   wpa-scan-ssid 1
   wpa-ap-scan 1
   wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
   wpa-proto RSN WPA
   wpa-pairwise CCMP TKIP
   wpa-group CCMP TKIP
   wpa-ssid SSIDWASHERE
   wpa-psk PSKWASHERE
```

Comment: I have a similar arrangement, albeit using dhcp, my configuration doesn't have the metric statement in the configuration of either interface

Comment: Since upgrading to Jessie, the system locks up after about 20 seconds if the wifi adapter is plugged in.  I am using a 2.4a charger.  I think the 1st generation Pi just doesn't have the guts to do much of anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try `allow-hotplug eth0` in the config above