# WiFi drops out when I remove ethernet cable

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ethernet

When the Ethernet cable is plugged in, WiFi works just perfectly. I can SSH and HTTP into the pi. However, when I remove the Ethernet cable, the WiFi drops out. The Gui shows that there are no WiFi adapters. There are very brief moments when the Ethernet adapter is removed that the WiFi still works, but usually stop within 15-20 second after pulling the plug, or fresh reboot.

I am not really familiar with Raspbian, so if you need any info please let me know what commands I need to run to get the info you need.  I do have an elementary understanding based of previous problems and issues I have searched on, but this is stumping my googling skills.

Comment: What is the ethernet cable plugged into while the wifi is on?

Comment: Looks like there's a similar (although unanswered) question [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/19851/40)

Comment: Ethernet cable is plugged into the router or right not temporarily plugged into a pc that is sharing it's ethernet port w/ the wifi card.  I am moving the pi away from the router, I got other equipment that I am hooking up to it, and I want the wifi working w/o ethernet.

Comment: I tried that answer, and it did not work..

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it is because the metric of the eth0 is lower than the wlan0. See more here: [Should wifi be turned off with wired connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50664/should-wifi-be-turned-off-with-wired-connection)