# WiFi only works properly with Ethernet

Tags: pi-3, networking, wifi

I have the following problem.

I want to have access on my Raspberry Pi 3 via WiFi. I have once set it up using the GUI, but now running it in the headless mode. The problem now is that this works for about 3 days then I can't connect to the Pi anymore.

I found out what I then need to do is to plug in the ethernet cable and then it works again. I have also seen that there are two default routes installed. One goes over `wlan0` and the other over `eth0`.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

So I assume that once I plug out the ethernet cable, the outgoing connections try to go over `eth0` instead of `wlan0`. When I then delete the entries for `eth0`, WiFi works again **but only for around 3 days**, then all starts over again.

The following are my configuration files for the `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
country=CH
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="SSID"
    psk=HashedPassword
}
```

Any ideas on that? Thanks

PS: I know that there is another [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19851/wifi-only-works-if-ethernet-is-plugged-in) related to this, but that approach did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, when you plug in an Ethernet cable, a connection is established via `eth0` instead of `wlan0`. Actually, when you have wlan on and an Ethernet cable connected, you can SSH through both connections simultaneously.

I had a similar problem with Wi-Fi. It turns out a manual reboot of the system every day helps the problem. Just set up a cronjob to reboot the Pi once a day. It resolved my problems.

Comment: Could it be power related? I had some funky happenstances when I had connected multiple low-power USB devices without a powered hub.

Comment: So I have now setup a crontab for a daily reboot, so I'll see tomorrow how it goes. @JamesFinch: I do not believe it is power related. At least I hope not, since I have the official power supply from Raspberry Pi.

Comment: So setting up the cronjob helped, but I don't think this is the right solution about this.