# WiFi doesn't work unless Ethernet is also connected

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

I have a problem with a brand new installation of Raspbian on a Pi 3 B+ (as well as on a Pi 4, with a stock install of Openhabian), one that has already come up [several](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19851/wifi-only-works-if-ethernet-is-plugged-in) [times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66753/wifi-only-works-properly-with-ethernet?newreg=e0050b4222544bd89eeb145c5d3c75b7). I have tried the solutions listed in those answers, modifying `/etc/network/interfaces`, but it didn't seem to help in the slightest - unless I have the Ethernet cable plugged in, the WiFi can't even get an IP, and with the cable connected, it's a crapshoot whether it gets a `169.254.x.x` IP or a proper `10.0.x.x` IP.

Contents of my interfaces config:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

`wpa_supplicant.conf` has the correct data for connecting to the network in question:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="SkyNet"
        psk="/*snip*/"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Additionally, it looks like while I can SSH into the device from the local network, the device can't communicate out towards the wider internet. The routing table doesn't show any *obvious* anomalies, though:

```
root@panel:/home/raspbian# ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.51 metric 202
default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 10.0.10.10 metric 303
10.0.0.0/16 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.10.10 metric 303
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.51 metric 202
```

Anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Seeing as Raspberry Pi OS hasn't used Debian networking for 8 years, and you got the settings wrong for that. This shows little research. Network Manager is not used by default.

Comment: Your wpa_supplicant file doesn't include `country=XX` (with the correct country code) so `rfkill` is probably disallowing connections.

Comment: @Dougie Good catch! Weirdly enough, it was connecting on-and-off without it, but now it seems to be more consistent.
The original issue persists, though, if I disconnect the cable, WiFi stops transmitting too...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Comment: Beautiful. I just noticed/confirmed that the Raspi Imager - the official utility for burning system images - does not add the `country=XX` key to the `wpa_supplicant.conf` even if you specify it before writing the image...

Comment: If you run a new image you should be prompted to specify location and if you configure with GUI it is set.

Comment: NOTE NetworkManager DOES NOT use wpa_supplicant. If you want to manually configure use nmcli. You are mixing incompatible networking services.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of @Milliways's comment, the solution in my case turned out to be commenting out everything in the interface config - `/etc/network/interfaces` - (aside from the inclusion rule) and restarting `networking` and `NetworkManager`.